# Custom ScrollView NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, scrollview

I have this custom view class as inner class:

```
public class GraphFragment extends SherlockFragment {
[...]
    public class FlingableScrollView extends ScrollView {
        public FlingableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                int defStyle) {
             super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public FlingableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
             super(context, attrs);
        }

         public FlingableScrollView(Context context) {
             super(context);
         }

         @Override
         public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
             super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
             return gestureListener.onTouch(this, ev);
         }
     }
}
```

and in my XML layout:

```
        <view
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.GraphFragment$FlingableScrollView" >
```

It doesn't work because of this error:

> 04-04 20:04:41.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2011): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class
>   android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem is raised in this question. See if it helps.

[Implementing extended/custom View throws NoSuchMethod for constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655347/implementing-extended-custom-view-throws-nosuchmethod-for-constructor)