# Custom view default style not wokring without style tag

Tags: android, android-custom-view, material-components-android

I have researched a lot and find many sources to this problem but no solutions working for me I don't know  what's going wrong.

> Some resources i have look into

[Custom view style, android's attributes are ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182411/custom-view-style-androids-attributes-are-ignored)

https://androidpedia.net/en/tutorial/1446/creating-custom-views

https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/how-to-support-themes-in-custom-views-for-android-apps

> This is repo for this problem

https://github.com/burhankhanzada199888/CustomView-Style-StackOverflow-Question/tree/master/app

I have 2 custom view in my activity first without style tag and second with style tag but cardView style only apply when using in xml

[image: main_activity]

> custom_view.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:parentTag="com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView"
    tools:style="@style/CustomCardView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="?colorSurface"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
 <com.myapp.CustomCardView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1" />

 <com.myapp.CustomCardView
     style="@style/CustomCardView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1" />
```

> CustomCardView.java

```
public class CustomCardView extends MaterialCardView {

public CustomCardView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomCardView, defStyleAttr, R.style.CustomCardView);

    float imageSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CustomCardView_imageSize, 0);
    float textSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CustomCardView_textSize, 0);

    a.recycle();

    inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this);

    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) imageSize;
    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) imageSize;

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setTextSize(textSize);

}
```

}

> styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomCardView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="cardElevation">8dp</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">?colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="imageSize">150dp</item>
    <item name="textSize">50sp</item>
</style>
```

> attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomCardView">
    <attr name="imageSize" format="dimension|reference" />
    <attr name="textSize" format="dimension|reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the `attrs.xml`:

```
<attr format="reference" name="customCardViewStyle"/>
```

Change the constructor:

```
public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
```

to

```
public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.customCardViewStyle);
}
```

Then in your app theme add:

```
<item name="customCardViewStyle">@style/CustomCardView</item>
```

Just pay attention to `<item name="android:layout_margin">...</item>`. The `LayoutParams` are specific to the parent view type and you can't apply it with a theme.You can set the layout attributes in a `style` on in the layout.

Answer (score -3):

It happens because you've removed super calls in `public CustomCardView(Context context)` and `public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` constructors. Indeed your constructors must be like these:

```
public CustomCardView(Context context) {
    super(context)
    this(context, null);
}
```

and

```
public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs)
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
```

Comment: IIRC, there's no actual need for calling _both_ the superclass' constructor and the custom class' constructor.