# Is there a way to force a style on a custom view?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, material-components-android

I have a custom view and I want to make it impossible to change the style on the XML.
This is the view

```
class PrimaryButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int =
R.attr.primary_button_style
) : MaterialButton(context, attributeSet, R.attr.primary_button_style)
```

and I want this to be impossible or do nothing.

```
<com.stuff.buttons.PrimaryButton
          android:id="@+id/first_button"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Primary Button"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          style="@style/Small.Secondary.Button"
```

I want to force always the primary_button_style.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom view style, android's attributes are ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182411/custom-view-style-androids-attributes-are-ignored)

Comment: not really, I don't have a layout to implement it's just a button with a specific style.
no attributes. just the style.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor `MaterialButton(context, attributeSet, R.attr.primary_button_style)` the
`primary_button_style` is an **attribute** defined in your app theme, it is **not a style**.

If you want to apply a different style you have to:

- Define a custom attribute in `attrs.xml`

```
<attr name="primary_button_style" format="reference"/>
```

- Assing a style to this attribute in your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
   <item name="primary_button_style">@style/App.Material3.Button</item>
</style>
```

- Define the custom style:

```
    <style name="App.Material3.Button" parent="Widget.Material3.Button">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/....</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: That's what I have, but it does not work. if I declare the style on the XML it will override that one.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues It's the standard behaviour of Android. You can't override it.